# remove duplicates with distinct() dplyr in R

Tags: r

using dplyr library
1. I need to create new object with 2 columns from mtcars table in df1
2. in df2, need 10 to 20 from df1
3. need to remove duplicates from df2 with both columns

```
df= mtcars %>% select(mpg,hp)
df2= slice(df,10:20)
distinct(df2, mpg,hp, .keep_all=TRUE)
```

here, distinct() does not print df2 without any duplicates, it's same with all the values. Maybe it has to do something with having list type. another observation is car names is used as row name in df but in df2 row names, are just numeric values.

how to remove duplicates with both the columns using dplyr?

Comment: You are asking for distinct columns where both mpg and hp are duplicates (there are none). `distinct(df2, hp, .keep_all=TRUE)` This will check for duplicates in hp.

Comment: `dplyr` verbs return `tbl_df`s. If you read through the docs (`?tibble::rownames`), it says rownames are dropped. If you need them, you can use `tibble::rownames_to_column` first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is we need to separate the distinct calls. If we use `distinct(df2, mpg,hp, .keep_all=TRUE)` we are asking for columns that do not have duplicates in both columns within the same row, this does not happen in the given data set so everything is returned.

If we first return all rows without duplicates in `hp` and then take that data and only return rows without duplicates in `mpg`, you will get the expected result.

```
library(dplyr)

df= mtcars %>% select(mpg,hp)
df2= slice(df,10:20)
df3<-distinct(df2, hp, .keep_all=TRUE)
df4<-distinct(df3, mpg, .keep_all=TRUE)

> df4
   mpg  hp
1 19.2 123
2 16.4 180
3 10.4 205
4 14.7 230
5 32.4  66
6 30.4  52
7 33.9  65
```